# one-to-many: making Hibernate select the reference's id instead of joining it

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, one-to-many

I have two classes stored in my database using Hibernate. Let's call them `Container` and `Item`. Item has a one-to-many relation to Container:

```
@entity(name = "containers")
public class Container {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
}

@entity(name = "items")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "container_id")
    private Container container;
}
```

I want to select select all for all items the tuple `[ (long)item.id, (long)item.container_id ]`, but Hibernate seems to insist on retrieving `[ (long)item.id, (Container)item.container ]`, introducing a useless (and expensive) join.

I tried that criteria query:

```
Criteria criteria = session.
    createCriteria(Link.class).
    add(Restrictions.isNotNull("container")).
    setProjection(Projections.projectionList().
        add(Projections.id()).
        add(Projections.property("container")));
```

Is there a matching criteria query. Has to be possible without HQL queries or native SQL queries, hasn't it?

**Edit 1:** Working HQL query:

```
session.createQuery("SELECT item.id, item.container.id " +
                    "FROM items AS item " +
                    "WHERE item.container <> NULL")
```

**Edit 2:** FetchType.LAZY is not an option.

Comment: FYI: Using `Projections.property("container_id")` throws "could not resolve property: container_id".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Link.class);
criteria.createAlias("container", "containerAlias");
criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("containerAlias.id"));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.id())
    .add(Projections.property("containerAlias.id")));
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be sufficient to add a `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` attribute to the `@ManyToOne` annotation. If you've annotated an `ID` column in Container, the test for whether `item.container` is null should not require a join.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible in my case, because for all but one maintenance method I need the fetch to be greedy.